# Alternate proof of riesz representation theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthogonality

I am having trouble understanding this remark on page 192 of Linear Algbera Done Right about the Riesz representation theorem.

[image]

The author claims that part d of this problem provides an alternate proof of the Riesz representation theorem in the case that F = R. However I am struggling to see why this is true. The Riesz representation theorem proves the existence and uniqueness of a vector u in V such that for all v and for *any* linear functional φ, φ(v) = <v,u>, and I don’t see how part d allows us to draw the same conclusion about *any* linear functional on V.

Comment: Maybe I’m wrong, but isn’t this just because $\Phi$ is (in particular) a surjection from $V$ to $V’$?

Comment: Your quantifiers are backwards in your statement of the Riesz representation theorem - maybe this is the source of your confusion. It doesn't say "there is a unique $u \in V$ such that for all $v$ and for any linear functional $\phi$, we have $\phi(v) = \langle v,u\rangle$". Rather, it says "for all linear functionals $\phi$, there is a unique $u \in V$ (depending on $\phi$) such that for all $v$, we have $\phi(v) = \langle v,u\rangle$". The reason the above proves this is that every $\phi$ is $\Phi u$ for some unique $u$ (by bijectivity of $\Phi$).